# ¿Alguien sabe como realizar pagos con la API de Binance? Uso el endpoint y el body recomendado por ellos con el método POST pero faltan los headers

Tags: api

https://binancepay/openapi/payout/transfer

```
{
  "env" : {
    "terminalType": "APP"
  },
  "merchantTradeNo": "9825382937292",
  "orderAmount": 25.17,
  "currency": "BUSD",
  "goods" : {
    "goodsType": "01",
    "goodsCategory": "D000",
    "referenceGoodsId": "7876763A3B",
    "goodsName": "Ice Cream",
    "goodsDetail": "Greentea ice cream cone"
  }
}
```

How to Generate API Signature

Step 1. Build the content

`String payload = timestamp+" \n"+nonce+" \n"+body+" \n"`

Step 2. Sign the content

`String signature = hex(hmac("sha512", payload, secretKey)).toUpperCase();`

Me da este Error: **getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND binancepay**

Comment: Hola Charly, bienvenido, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edita tu pregunta elimina las imágenes, y agrega tu código y el mensaje de error como texto, gracias. Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Answer (score 0):

Listo, ya lo hice, dejo el repositorio en Github por si alguien esta interesado y agrego también los script para consultar las transacciones en PHP y Javascript:

https://github.com/carlosAthena/Pagos-con-la-API-de-Binance/tree/main

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).